# jQuery: is there a better solution for this task?

Tags: jquery

Here is an HTML menu code:

```
<div class="sub-menu">
  <div class="sub-rubric menu-item"><a href="#">RUBRIC -1-</a></div>
  <div class="menu-item"><a href="/link/">1111111</a></div>

  <div class="sub-rubric menu-item"><a href="#">RUBRIC -2-</a></div>
  <div class="menu-item"><a href="/link/">2222222</a></div>
  <div class="menu-item"><a href="/link/">3333333</a></div>
  <div class="menu-item"><a href="/link/">4444444</a></div>
  <div class="menu-item"><a href="/link/">5555555</a></div>

  <div class="sub-rubric menu-item"><a href="#">RUBRIC -3-</a></div>
  <div class="menu-item"><a href="/link/">6666666</a></div>
  <div class="menu-item"><a href="/link/">6666666</a></div>
</div>
```

Note that some `<div>` have a class `"sub-rubric"` and they lead groups of `<div class="menu-item">` elements.

The idea is to wrap each group of `div.menu-item` elements lead by `div.sub-rubric` with a `<div>` element.

**The result must be like this:**

```
<div class="sub-menu">

  <div class="sub-rubric-wrap">
    <div class="sub-rubric menu-item"><a href="#">RUBRIC -1-</a></div>
    <div class="menu-item"><a href="/link/">1111111</a></div>
  </div>

  <div class="sub-rubric-wrap">
    <div class="sub-rubric menu-item"><a href="#">RUBRIC -2-</a></div>
    <div class="menu-item"><a href="/link/">2222222</a></div>
    <div class="menu-item"><a href="/link/">3333333</a></div>
    <div class="menu-item"><a href="/link/">4444444</a></div>
    <div class="menu-item"><a href="/link/">5555555</a></div>
  </div>

  <div class="sub-rubric-wrap">
    <div class="sub-rubric menu-item"><a href="#">RUBRIC -3-</a></div>
    <div class="menu-item"><a href="/link/">6666666</a></div>
    <div class="menu-item"><a href="/link/">6666666</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here is my solution:**

```js
while ($('.sub-menu').children('.sub-rubric').length > 0) {
    $('.sub-menu').children('.sub-rubric').first()
        .nextUntil('.sub-rubric')
        .add($('.sub-menu').children('.sub-rubric').first())
        .wrapAll('<div class="sub-rubric-wrap"></div>');
}
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sub-rubric a {
  color: black;
}

.sub-rubric-wrap {
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub-menu">
  <div class="sub-rubric menu-item"><a href="#">RUBRIC -1-</a></div>
  <div class="menu-item"><a href="/link/">1111111</a></div>

  <div class="sub-rubric menu-item"><a href="#">RUBRIC -2-</a></div>
  <div class="menu-item"><a href="/link/">2222222</a></div>
  <div class="menu-item"><a href="/link/">3333333</a></div>
  <div class="menu-item"><a href="/link/">4444444</a></div>
  <div class="menu-item"><a href="/link/">5555555</a></div>

  <div class="sub-rubric menu-item"><a href="#">RUBRIC -3-</a></div>
  <div class="menu-item"><a href="/link/">6666666</a></div>
  <div class="menu-item"><a href="/link/">6666666</a></div>
</div>
```

**Is there a better way to do that?**

Comment: need to move this question to :- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Wrapping `li` element is not `valid` HTML syntax. wrap it with `ul, li`

Comment: ul child is only li not div

Comment: Why do you want to wrap the list items in divs? IMHO, it seems to be bad semantics. You should perhaps have nested lists.

Comment: Your html is not validated. You can't use div inside ul.

Comment: Let's consider this task as just a jQuery training :)

Comment: @Zurab-D Training or not, javascript can't work with html that is broken.

Comment: Just change all the `ul`s and `li`s to divs and the invalid html goes away while keeping the actual issue that should be on codereview.

Comment: @freedomn-m ok, I fixed that, thanks a lot